# Complex Probability Trees

Tags: probability

This is a cross post from stackoverflow/java - someone suggested that it might be better posted over here :)

---

Hiya there wonderful people,

I want to write a Hearthstone RNG calculator.

Hopefully, to those that have played the game - this will make a little bit of sense - to those that haven't - sorry! :)

**The Problem**

> The enemy has 4 minions with health `[1, 3, 4, 20]`
>
> Once the health of an enemy reaches `0` they are considered destroyed and are removed from play (for example - it is impossible for minions to have -1 health)
>
> Once a minion is destroyed/removed from play it cannot be targeted by any more missiles.
>
> I cast the spell Avenging Wrath - which generates `8` separate, random missiles which can hit any of the `4` targets.
>
> Each missile deals exactly `1` damage.

How can I work out the probability that say, the minion with 3 health dies? `[x, 0, x, x]`
How likely is it that it none of them die? `[1, 3, 4, 12]`

I imagine I will need to use decision trees calculate the outcome after each possible missile hit.

Any chance anyone can point me in the right direction?

Thanks for looking :)